# No server response ASP.NET Core after using Include

Tags: api, server

I have a weird issue with server response from my database using ASP.NET Core.

So CASE 1 returns 200 OK and a nice list

```
public IActionResult GetTrades(int id)
{
    var positions = context.Trades.Where(x=>x.WebClientId==id).ToList();
    return Ok(positions);
}
```

However inside this Trades table I have other objects which are referenced by their id and I want to reach them as well so I use Include().

```
public IActionResult GetTrades(int id)
{
    var positions = context.Trades.Where(x=>x.WebClientId==id)
                    .Include(s=>s.Strategy)
                    .Include(p=>p.Portfolio).ToList();

    return Ok(positions);
}
```

Now here is where strange things start to happen. I get no response in Postman. No error, nothing, just could not get any response.

However if I go into the debug mode and put a breakpoint on return, everything I need is there, all objects are there, I can go inside every single one of them, Strategy, Portfolio, and look at all the model details.

Hopefully someone else had a similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a loop inside a domain model. I had to use AutoMapper and a separete Resources model to eleminate the loop and everything started working.

For example:

In the Trade model class there was a reference to the Portfolio model class like this:

```
public Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; } //virtual for lazy loading
public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
```

In the Porfolios class there was a reference to the Trades class like this:

```
 public IList<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
```

I recreated both classes as PortfolioResource and TradeResource without the loop and edited the controller to use AutoMapper like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TradeResource>> GetPositions(int id)
{

    var positions = await context.Trades
         .Where(x => x.WebClientId == id)
        .Include(s => s.Strategy)
        .Include(p => p.Portfolio)
         .ToListAsync();

    return mapper.Map<List<Trade>, List<TradeResource>>(positions);
}
```

I also created a mapping profile for this after proper installation of AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core using

1) dotnet add package AutoMapper
2) dotnet add package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependancyInjection
3) dotnet restore

Also added services.AddAutoMapper(); to StartUp.cs in the ConfigureServices

FInally the mapper class.

```
public class MappingProfie:Profile
{
    public MappingProfie()
    {
        CreateMap<Trade, TradeResource>();
        CreateMap<Portfolio, PortfolioResource>();
        CreateMap<WebClient, WebClientResource>();
        CreateMap<Strategy, StrategyResource>();
    }
}
```

Everything started working after this.